# Java how to stop thread if the program was closed

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm getting some exception and I need to know when the program closes itself because I need to close the socket.

I have the default public static main method where I'm keep repeating an action and a Thread class.

```
private static Thread thread;
public static boolean isRunning = true;  

public static void main(String[] args){

   thread = new Thread(new ThreadListenServer());
   thread.start();

   Timer timer = new Timer();
   TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
      @Override
      public void run(){
         // some action
      }
   }

   timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, 0, 10000);

   isRunning = false;
}
```

And the thread class which is running in background:

```
public class ThreadListenServer implements Runnable{

    private DatagramSocket socket;

    public ThreadListenServer() throws SocketException{
       socket = new DatagramSocket(6655);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

       while(MainProgram.isRunning){
            // some action
       }

       socket.close();
    }
}
```

I don't know why, but `isRunning` it's becoming false, but it shouldn't. How am I supposed to close the socket if the main program was closed? (It's causing because the Thread still running in the background even if the program was closed).

I was thinking about to create the socket in the main class then I pass the socket object as a parameter to the ThreadClass and if the program is closed, than I should close the socket as well.

Comment: When you close a process it will close all it's resources including sockets.

Comment: It's becoming false because you are setting it to false.

Comment: Consider using Executors instead of separate Threads.  Much easier to regain control when they are done.

Answer (score 4):

Use:

```
thread.setDaemon(true);
```

This will shut the thread. It tells the JVM it is a background thread , so it will shut down on exit.

Answer (score 2):

A few things come to mind.

1. It would appear you are performing a blocking I/O operation using sockets. You may need to interrupt either the running thread and/or the socket to get it to stop blocking
2. You should set the thread as daemon thread before it is started, using `setDaemon(true)`. This will allow the JVM to terminate the thread automatically...
3. `isRunning` should be marked `volatile` or you should use `AtomicBoolean` instead

Answer (score 2):

Ill take the assumption you have a JFrame of some sort running as the class MainProgram. You have 2 options

1: set your Jframe to close all threads when it is closed.

```
setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

2: add a window listener and manually close your thread (maybe you have to send some information across the socket before you close it)

```
addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
  public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
    // send your socket its close message and shut everything down
    System.exit(0);
  }
});
```

Comment: The JVM will only exit when all NON daemon threads have terminated, this will not make any difference to the OPs problem

Comment: Take a look at the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html) for a better description

Comment: @MadProgrammer I am aware of daemon threads but by defualt threads are not daemon and I do not see OP setting them to be so. Also calling System.exit should shutdown all those threads. If not then option 2 is still viable (and the best IMO) to send shutdown messages to all threads and close up shop.

Comment: By default threads are NOT DAEMON, when the JVM exists, the OPs thread WILL NOT be automatically terminated by the JVM and will be allowed to run until it exists of its own accord. I also see no evidence that this has anything to with swing, for the code example, comments or tags, so at best, this is comment, at worst it's a guess

Answer (score 1):

To stop all Threads when your program exits **cleanly**, you'll need to define a termination policy for each Thread that gets started. This is normally done using `Interrupts` and `ExecutorService.shutdownNow()` method sends an interrupt to each running thread.

A clean termination policy consists to two parts:

- Sending stop signal to thread – aka interrupting it
- Designing threads to act on interruption

A thread in Java could be interrupted by calling `Thread.interrupt()` method. Threads can check for interruption by calling `Thread.isInterrupted()` method. A good thread must check for interruption at regular intervals, e.g. as a loop condition and checking blocking functions for `InterruptedExceptions`.

It is important to note that `Socket`s in Java are oblivious to interruption. For example, if a Thread is blocked on `Socket.accept()`, it will not throw `InterruptedException` when the Thread is interrupted. In this case, you need to define a public method which closes the underlying socket by calling `Socket.close()` forcing the blocking function to throw an Exception (I guess `SocketException`).